Nouveau driver not working with RTX 3060 mobile
In my past experience, Fedora's Nouveau driver worked splendidly by default. In fact I would have try and disable it to get the proprietary NVIDIA to take over. However the Nvidia driver is a lot of maintenance, and its hard to get it to run with secure-boot, and I am tired of it tainting my kernel. So I wanted to give the Mesa, Nouveau, and NVK a try. My primary need right now is compute with OpenCL.
I have a dual setup with a integrated radeon GPU, and an RTX 3000 series Nvidia GPU.
I started by removing all things Nvidia
dnf remove \*nvidia\*
dnf remove \*cuda\*

I installed the drivers, but some issues, got a tip to install the Nvidia firmware
dnf install nvidia-gpu-firmware

I did that, it got rid of some errors in journalctl but I still had problems, I reinstalled the drivers but the problems persisted, here are some of the issues I am having:
clinfo gives the following errors:
nvc0_screen_create:1002 - Base screen init failed: -19

and
=== CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG ===
<built-in>:1:10: fatal error: 'clc/clc.h' file not found

It looks like it is trying to query the nvidia device but failing, I get the first error when I compile and run my own OpenCL Programs.
vulkaninfo hangs and journalctl gives
fedora abrt-dump-journal-oops[2001]: abrt-dump-journal-oops: Creating problem directories
fedora abrt-dump-journal-oops[2001]: abrt-dump-journal-oops: Found oopses: 1
fedora kernel: note: vulkaninfo[119113] exited with irqs disabled

When it runs, along with what looks like some sort of call stack/dump.
glxgears and inxi -Gx also hang though inxi does work, but it does not show the nvidia gpu (just my AMD integrated one).
I don't know if these journalctl messages are relevant
fedora gnome-shell[1342]: Added device '/dev/dri/card1' (nouveau) using non-atomic mode setting.
fedora gnome-shell[1342]: Device '/dev/dri/card1' prefers shadow buffer

nouveau [REDACTED]: fb: VPR locked, but no scrubber binary!

Somewhat at a loss, I don't know the next step to debug or solve the problem, can anyone please help me to get open source OpenCL drivers to work on my Nvidia GPU (along possibly with NVK) please? :)
Thanks!
UPDATE (occurred after P.s)
After a system update vulkaninfo started working and showing the nvidia driver, however OpenCL programs seem to still struggle (clinfo still does not recognize it) or crash when retrieving the Nvidia GPU info.
clinfo no longer gets
nvc0_screen_create:1002 - Base screen init failed: -19

but still gets
=== CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG ===
<built-in>:1:10: fatal error: 'clc/clc.h' file not found

and does not display info about the Nvidia GPU.
inxi -Gx now displays (with redaction)
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] vendor: Lenovo
    driver: nouveau v: kernel arch: Ampere bus-ID: REDACT
  Device-2: AMD Cezanne [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Mobile Series]
    vendor: Lenovo driver: amdgpu v: kernel arch: GCN-5 bus-ID: REDACT

I did a fresh reinstall of the drivers + reboot and this persisted.
I have a slight issue with the firmware update tool, unsure if its related
FuUsbDevice          failed to parse platform BOS descriptor: failed to parse: no supported platform version: did not find magic

P.s I have a memory of doing something to disable the Nouveau driver a while back, so that my second monitor could be displayed via a direct graphics card connection (because nouveau didn't seem to do that). I already reversed configurations and boot parameters in grub blacklisting Nouveau (I think), but there may have been something else, I don't know if it would have anything to do with it... trying to figure it out if there is any configuration left, I think it may have had to do with GDM.
UPDATE:
Thanks to a chat with the developers in the freedesktop  chat room I actually did get this working, had something to do with Clover if I recall. I have to go back and check what I did, but I may post it here after I do that

Nouveau does not support well if at all the GeForce 30 generation. Please reinstall the NVIDIA own driver.

Thanks for the comment, do you include NVK when you say that? I did eventually get this working

NVK is highly experimental at this point. I have zero faith in it. Have fun with kernel crashes, freezes and crashing and misbehaving applications. Linux fans just love to create problems for themselves.
